# EXACT search on a custom field instead of LIKE

Tags: joomla, search-results

How do I do an EXACT search on a custom field – so instead of ending up with “LIKE” %Eastern Metropolitan%, in the search results I have an EXACT match?

I tried “Eastern_Metropolitan” “Eastern-Metropolitan” but I still get this result (with the word LIKE) - i.e STATE_UPPER_HOUSE Like %Eastern_Metropolitan% - which shows “South-Eastern” and “Eastern Metropolitan” also.

Here is how do the search

1. Advanced Search
   •   Address Fields: Australia + Victoria
   •   CUSTOM Fields - ELECTORATES:  State_upper_house = “Eastern Metropolitan”
2. After exporting the file and reviewing it we notice 2 things:
   a.  The list contains contacts with state_upper_electorate as “South-Eastern” and “Eastern Metropolitan”
   b.  There is an error on the first row of the .csv which not sure what this means;

   - **Warning**:  strpos(): Empty needle in **/home/righttolife/www/www/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Export/BAO/Export.php** on line **621**

Answer (score 1):

Hi from across the ditch.

Not clear if your custom field is text or select. Assuming Text (which raises the question of why isn't it select)

You can use Search Builder for this. Search > Search Builder.

Select contact type that your custom fields apply to. Set operator to =

Outcomes:

No matches found for:
Contact Type = 'Individual' ...AND...
electorate freehand = East

1 Contact
Contact Type = 'Individual' ...AND...
electorate freehand = Eastern Metropolitan

Does that help?

Fields are on http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/search/builder for the next x(<24) hours